# AS3: Property is Read Only

Tags: actionscript-3

I suck at coding and I'm having a bit of a problem fixing this error,

My code is this

```
private function changingTime(e:MouseEvent):void 
    {
        if (e.currentTarget == Barrier) 
        {
            e.currentTarget = new BlankSpot;
        }
```

My error is this: 
Game.as(179): 1059: Property is read-only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation of [currentTarget](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/Event.html#currentTarget) clearly states that it is a read-only property. Read-only property means you can only access it's value, but can not assign a new value. So `e.currentTarget = new BlankSpot;` is invalid. If you need to change `currentTarget` in this way, then may be you need to use a temporary variable and use that instead.

Comment: What I'm trying to do is change the class Object that I click on from one thing into another. Is there a way you could recommend doing this following the advice you gave me?

Comment: @Snolanda without some more details what you are trying to do its hard to tell how to do. May be you can use a separate variable as I said in the answer. The bottom line is: you can't change `currentTarget`.